# Excel Wildcard for any digit?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, c#, wildcards

I am trying to do a CRTL + F (Find) and look for any digit in the worksheet. In word you can use a wildcard of ^# which finds any digit. I'm using this to search sheets for stuff that fits a certain format but i don't have the actual number. For example, if i'm looking for a phone number in a word document i can go

```
^#^#^#-^#^#^#-^#^#^#^#
```

This will find any phone numbers within the document. I need to use the find feature for what i have setup.

Currently i am using ? wildcard but there are some things that are in the same format that aren't numbers and it is causing issues.

Comment: What does `C#` have to do with the question?

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm using the find feature in excel from c#. it uses the same search feature just from a c# application. I just need to know if the find feature has the capability or not.

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't. Why not read the value of a cell and process it in c#?

Comment: I'm currently searching to see if it exists in many excel documents rather then reading one individual cell form one worksheet/workbook. I'm not returning anything just checking if the documents have them.@cybernetic.nomad

Answer (score 0):

If you are a programmer, then the solution is likely within your skill set. Not mine, but in yours for sure.

Look at the following for setting up Excel to use regular exporessions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Then use VBA to do the work.

Regular Expressions seem to have been built for exactly your needs.

Comment: No need for Regular Expressions in this instance. If one is just looking for digits, you can use `Like` in VBA which has a wildcard digit category.  Still have to examine every cell, however, which is what I think the OP was trying to avoid.